# Sql query multiple tables yii2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I have two [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QguTV.png)

In my Search Model i wrote `public function frontendProvider(){}` to provide sql query to my view.

```
public function frontendProvider()
{

    $query = new Query;
    $query  ->select('strategy_title')  
            ->from('strategy')
            ->join( 'LEFT', 
                'risk_colors',
                'risk_colors.id = risk_colors_id'
            );         
    $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $query->createCommand()->queryAll(),
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'risk_colors_id' => SORT_DESC, 

            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'strategy_title', 
                'strategy_description', 
                'strategy_current_money',
                'color_number',
                'risk_colors_id',
            ],
        ],
    ]); 

    return $provider;
}
```

When i try to reload i`ve got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dwow.png). What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the join() method you must pass the complete JOIN type so in this case  you   should use  `LEFT JOIN`.. otherwsie you could use the esplicit leftJoin() method

```
    ..... 
    ->join('LEFT JOIN',
          'risk_colors',
            'risk_colors.id = risk_colors_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`leftJoin()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#leftJoin()-detail) method if you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
$query->select('strategy_title')  
      ->from('strategy')
      ->leftJoin( 
          'risk_colors',
          'risk_colors.id = risk_colors_id'
      );
```